# How to transfer control from Javascript to ASP.Net page from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to .Net. I searched and Googled a lot but couldn't find the solution for my issue.

I have an ASP.Net application. In my login page I only have a user id field. When the user submits the button, I need to have a transitional ASP page (page which user doesn't see but runs in background) which will run some Javascript and transfer the control to either page a or page b based on some condition. How do I achieve this?

How do I call a controller action from Javascript in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Such checks are ideally done on the server itself. Sending a intermediate page to the client and the redirecting is a slower option(Network delays).

To call a particular controller action you only have to redirect the user to that url.

In javascript you can use

```
location.href = URL_TO_CONTROLLER;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ajax function to call a controller action

example...

```
                 function Foo(textInput) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName?parameter1=" + textInput
                        success: function (data) {

                          //add code here

                     });
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
            function OnSubmitClick(UserID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/YourControllerName/YourActionName",
                    data: { "selectedID": UserID },
                    success: function (data) {



                 });
              }
```